# How to pass a string with a function?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to have a function that gives the time. I already have a time label in my app that displays the current time, and updates every second. But I want to have a label that only holds the time a button is pressed. There are multiple buttons that store the current time in different labels.

```
func fetchTime() -> String {
    return NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle)
    }

@IBAction func clockIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    testLabel = fetchTime()
```

The error I get is "Use of unresolved identifier 'fetch time'

I had this working awhile ago, but I accidentally deleted the app...
I also tried

```
    func fetchTime(label: String) -> String{
label.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle)

}
```

But that failed badly, and I understand why, just not how to do it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is your both tried working version...

version1

```
func fetchTime(label: UILabel){
    label.text = "its with parameter"
}

@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    fetchTime(label)
}
```

And the another one...

```
func fetchTime() -> String {
    return "without parameter"
}

@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    lbl.text = fetchTime()
}
```

Comment: Neither solution is working for me. On my own, I had the lbl.text = fetchTime(), I forgot to type it in the code in my question, sorry! I updated the question with a picture showing my code, and the error I get for 'Version 1'

Answer (score 0):

What you want to fetch is a string and that should be assigned as a label's text value.

Update

```
testLabel = fetchTime()
```

to

```
testlabel.text = fetchTime()
```

This will update the label's value each time when button is pressed.

Comment: This will work according to what you shown that time, only a function but now you have updated your question with a photo, I can see the problem is in syntax, after correcting syntax this will work.

Comment: Thank you, Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The picture you posted was helpful. You've declared the fetchTime function inside the scope of the updateTime function. You'll notice the curly braces for updateTime wrap around fetchTime.

This being the case you can not call fetchTime outside of updateTime. Move fetchTime out of updateTime and you'll be ok. That is why you are seeing the undefined function error message.